# Textures not loading; browser reporting same origin security error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to learn some three.js using some tutorials, but I keep getting this error, when trying to use textures:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at [any path here] may not be loaded.
```

The code I'm using is from this demo:

http://thegregstier.appspot.com/three-light-tut.html

The files are here:

http://sdg.repositoryhosting.com/git_public/sdg/sdg-blog.git/tree/HEAD:/Three-js-examples?js=1

I ran the same code locally with the same textures and I got the error I mentioned. Then I ran the same code with a XAMPP server open (Apache and MySQL modules loaded) and the files in the /htdocs/ folder. I still get the same error.

I tested in Chromium (41.0.2222.0 (64-bit)), Firefox (35.0.1) and Safari, both in Windows 8.1 and on OS X. I have admin accounts on all systems.

I didn't try using Chromium with local file access flag enabled yet, I'm hoping there should be another solution that doesn't lower the browser's security level.

Comment: Can you show us a full URL of one of the textures that isn't being loaded?

Comment: Well, first I tried with the textures from those links, but it didn't work. So I thought it might have something to do with the same-origin policy of files loaded from another URL. So, I saved all the files from the repo on my computer and ran the demo locally, with the same files. Again, textures didn't load.
So I loaded a local server (XAMPP) and placed all the files in the htdocs/ folder. Again they didn't load in any broswer. I suppose I have to run the browser with local files access enabled, but I don't like lowering the security of the browser just to make three.js work.

Comment: I could test it on another server and see if it works. But I wanted to be able to work with the demos locally so I can edit them and have the result feedback immediately.

Comment: It does have something to do with the Same Origin Policy, that's true.

By default browsers do not allow file:/// URLs in XHRs either, so running from the filesystem isn't an option either (unless you lower security settings in your browser config)

What's wrong with a local web server?

Comment: I've tested with a local server too and it still didn't work. It outputs the same error message with same-origin policy. That's why I'm asking here, because normally it should run on a local server.

Comment: Alright, that's weird. Would you mind running it off a local webserver and paste the full URL that you visit in your browser plus one of the failing URLs for us?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I created a new shortcut to Chrome using the --allow-file-access-from-files flag and it now works with the server loaded. All the webgl/three.js stuff works now. So, the problem was still caused by Chrome, not by the server or the files. It's not a good solution, but it's a solution which works.